# How to use ARRAYFORMULA with TEXTJOIN?

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google Sheet document and I use TEXTJOIN in it. I want to have my TEXTJOIN formula filled when i add new rows. But it doesn't work

[image]

So I tried to use ARRAYFORMULA. IT works with numbers:

[image]

But it still doesn't work with TEXTJOIN:

[image]

Any Ideas?

UPD: If I use `&` instead of `TEXTJOIN` it works but in fact i shoud use delimiter and I should avoid double delimiter. I shouldn't have any `a--a` or `d-D-`:
[image]

Comment: In response to your update: to remove duplicate delimiters you could use "SUBSTITUTE".
Of course this would only work if 1/ double delimiters don't appear in the data (but it is probably possible to use a temporary delimiter to avoid this) 2/ two successive columns can't be empty (but substitutions can be stacked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving multiple array ranges to Arrayformula, and trying to force it to evaluate it in a specific order, is a losing battle. Try something simpler instead:

```
=arrayformula(A1:A & " " & B1:B)
```

[image]

P.S. Your animated illustrations do show a level of effort on your part to ask a nice question, but frankly my eyes hurt from watching 3 cursors simultaneously, I'd prefer just the formulas or static images.

Comment: Seem's that this is the only way. But if I dont't have `TEXTJOIN` - I've got new problem. 
I've updated first message.

Comment: To eliminate the double delimiters, a regexreplace() on the result of the simple concatenation might be cleaner than a series of ifblank()'s

Answer (score 4):

Sheets now has a [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) function that you can use instead of ARRAYFORMULA.

You use a formula like this in column C:

```
=MAP(A1:A,B1:B,LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,{a,b}))
```

The lambda will be called for each row, with the value of column A and column B for the row passed as the first two params of the lambda function.

Comment: omg, this is incredible! Had not heard about map(). Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAP(B2:B8,LAMBDA(array,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(B2:F8,ROW(array)-1,))))

=MAP( rangeOfHowManyRows, LAMBDA( aName, TEXTJOIN(delimiter, TRUE, INDEX( fullRange, ROW(aName)-1, ) ) ) )
```

The use of `INDEX` makes spanning many columns much less painful.